# Angular blob response, not converting back.to json

Tags: angular

I am using an interceptor to be able to create mocking of data while my API isn;t ready yet within Angular. The mocking service handles all responses as BLOBS back to the frontend however I do not really understand how to convert the response back as a stream to a json result. I found that within the resquest I can state the response type is blob but then still it doesný give me back the result of the stream.

Let me illustrate it by code.

My mock service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpResponse,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MockResponseOptions } from './mock.types';
import { handleEchoRequest } from './responses/echo';
import { handleCasesRequest } from "./responses/cases";

@Injectable()
export class MockInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  // Mock API handler configuration
  private handlers = {
    GET: {
      // 'assets': handleGetAssetRequest
      // ...add new GET request handlers here
      '/cases': handleCasesRequest
    },

    POST: {
      '/echo': handleEchoRequest,
      // ...add new POST request handlers here


    },
  };

  constructor() { }

  /**
   * Intercepts HTTP requests and returns mock response if configured and actual response otherwise
   * @param {HttpRequest} request The request to be mocked.
   * @param {HttpHandler} next The real HTTP request handler
   * @returns {Observable<HttpEvent>}
   */
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const mockHandler = this.getMockHandler(request);

    if (mockHandler) {
      console.log('[REQUEST INTERCEPTED]', request);
      const mockResponseConfig = mockHandler(request);

      return this.getResponse(mockResponseConfig, request);
    }

    // If no mock handler is available, perform the original request
    return next.handle(request);
  }

  /**
   * Creates an Observable HttpResponse based on a mock response configuration.
   * @param {MockResponseOptions} options The mock response configuration
   * @param {HttpRequest<unknown>} request The original HTTP request
   */
  getResponse(
    options: MockResponseOptions,
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<Blob>> {

    console.log('[REQUEST after interception]', request, options);
    return of(
      new HttpResponse({
        status: options.status || 200,
        body: new Blob([JSON.stringify(options.body, null, 2)], {
          type: 'application/json',
        }),
        url: request.url,
      })
    ).pipe(delay(options.delay || 1000));
  }

  /**
   * Returns a mocking handler for an HTTP request if configured and null otherwise.
   * @param {HttpRequest} request The request to be mocked.
   */
  getMockHandler({ method, url }: HttpRequest<unknown>) {
    const methodHandlers = this.handlers[method] || [];

    // Check if the current request's URL ends with the URL of a handler
    for (const handlerUrl in methodHandlers) {
      if (url.endsWith(handlerUrl)) {
        return methodHandlers[handlerUrl];
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

My mock cases response:

```
import { HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MockResponseOptions } from '../mock.types';

/**
 * Returns mock HTTP response configuration for cases request
 * @param {HttpRequest} request The request to be mocked.
 */
export function handleCasesRequest(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>
): MockResponseOptions {
    // POST data is a JSON-encoded string in request.body

    // let data = { data: "test returned" };
    console.log('mock response triggered!');

    const data = [
        {
            item: 1
        },
        {
            item: 2
        },
        {
            item: 3
        }
    ];

    return {
        body: { output: `${JSON.stringify(data)}` },
    };
}
```

My component

```
import { actionButtonTypes } from './../../models/enums/actionButtonEnum';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as env from "../../environments/environment"
import { handleCasesRequest } from "../../../../../libs/abf-api-mock/src/lib/responses/cases"
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { delay, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'abf-lease-contract-overview',
  templateUrl: './lease-contract-overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lease-contract-overview.component.scss']
})
export class LeaseContractOverviewComponent implements OnInit {

  uploadIconText = actionButtonTypes.Upload;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  response: any;

  private async fetchData() {
    this.response = "";
    this.response = await this.http
      .get("http://localhost:4200/cases", { responseType: 'blob' })
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          console.log('dit is de response', response)
          return response;
        })
      ).subscribe(data => {
        return data;
      }
      )
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchData();

  }

}
```

What happens in dev tools
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: responseType: 'blob' try to remove this and add 'json'

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to do that but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Can you say what you getting from backened(http://localhost:4200/cases)
and add the response.......
If u don't know the exact format type in chrome or search engine this url http://localhost:4200/cases